# Showing that a sequence of arbitrary real numbers is contractive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am having trouble with the following problem.

> If $x_1<x_2$ are arbitrary real numbers and $x_n = \frac{1}{3}x_{n-1}+\frac{2}{3}x_{n-2}$ for $n>2$, show that ${x_n}$ (a sequence) is convergent.

Notes: I know that the key to this problem is to show that ${x_n}$ is a contractive sequence. If it is contractive I can prove it is convergent. But, I do not know how to prove it is contractive. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|x_n-x_{n-1}|=|{1\over 3}x_{n-1}+{2\over 3}x_{n-2}-x_{n-1}|={2\over 3}|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}|=({2\over 3})^{n-2}|x_2-x_1|$. Deduce that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.
$|x_{n+m}-x_n|\leq|x_{n+m}-x_{n+m-1}|+...+|x_{m+1}-x_m|\leq ({2\over 3})^{m-1}(1+{2\over 3}+..+({2\over 3})^{n-1})|x_2-x_1|\leq 3({2\over 3})^{m-1}|x_2-x_1|.$
Thus the sequence converges.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @TsemoAristide . Other readers might want to use the following answer if they can use external proofs:

\begin{align*}
|x_n-x_{n-1}|&=|({1\over 3}x_{n-1}+{2\over 3}x_{n-2})-x_{n-1}| \text{ substitue the value of $x_n$} \\ 
&={2\over 3}|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}| \text{ We can now see that $\{x_n\}$ is contractive}
\end{align*}

Thus as every contractive sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and all Cauchy sequences converge, $\{x_n\}$ must converge.